# ajax response from string to array

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this ajax code that it is returning an array as a string. I need to display the first value or second of the array. Like response.total or response[0].

Here is what I get back from the response when I do a console.log(response):

```
{"total":1,"type":"like"}
```

And here is my ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pin/like?pinId='+pinId,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {actionSignature: actionSignature, actionSignatureSeed: actionSignatureSeed},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response[0]);
            likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> "+likeButton.attr('data-text-'+response[1]));
            likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> " + response[0]);
            likeButton.removeClass('disabled');
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert('An error occurred, please reload the page and try again.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: That isn't an array, that's an object containing two properties total (which = 1) and type (which = like). It's not clear what you want to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like the JSON being returned is castable as an array, it represents a javascript object with two properties (total and type).

Are you certain it's a string and not the actual object (the console will generally render it in that eye-readable format)? If it's definitely a string then you can include the open source `json2.js` file in your page, and cast it back into an object using something like

```
var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
```

However if it's already returning the object (quite possibly the case), then you can access it's properties with

```
response.total
```

and

```
response.type
```

(which will return "1" and "like" respectively)

Comment: I get back an undefined after doing console.log(response.total)

Comment: Yes it did work. I added the dataType JSON and that was why I was getting the undefined. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `dataType: 'JSON'` to your `$.ajax` options. That way JSON string is automatically converted into javascript object and you can use `response.total` and `response.type`.

Be aware though - if your response isn't a JSON string, an `error:` part of your request will be triggered.

Comment: though relevant, this should probably be a comment as it will not solve the problem

Comment: Altered my response abit to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Json returns as a string.  You need to parse it.  Otherwise response[0] will just be "{". Then, you can access the object with response.total and response.type.

```
$.ajax({
url: '/pin/like?pinId='+pinId,
type: 'POST',
data: {actionSignature: actionSignature, actionSignatureSeed: actionSignatureSeed},
    success: function(response) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(response);
        likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> "+likeButton.attr('data-text-'+response.type));
        likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> " + response.total);
        likeButton.removeClass('disabled');
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('An error occurred, please reload the page and try again.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
 likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> "+likeButton.attr('data-text-'+response.type));
 likeButton.html("<i class='icon-heart'></i> " + response.total);
```